# Client downloading entire data from firebase when queried with a filter for few rows

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We have a feed implementation in Android, where we use firebase as the realtime database. We have turned on persistence on firebase and implemented paginated queries to display users feed. Each users feed will have few thousands of feed data, but only 10 are fetched to display to the user, with the next page fetched on scroll.

The following is the pagination code

```
Query mQueryRef = mDatabaseRef.child(FirebaseConstants.FEED_PATH).child(feedId).child(FirebaseConstants.TILES_PATH);
    mQueryRef.keepSynced(KEEP_SYNCED);
    mQueryRef.orderByChild(FirebaseConstants.UPDATED_AT_FIELD_PATH)
            .limitToLast(numOfTiles)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(getValueEventListener(fbReqParam, firebaseCallback));
```

An index is specified for FirebaseConstants.UPDATED_AT_FIELD_PATH as below

```
    {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "feed": {
        "$feedId": {
            "tiles": {
                "$tileId": {
                    ".indexOn": "/header/updatedAt",    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
  }
}
```

The following is the data model
[image: DataModel]

However, we have seen that the entire data for a specified feedId is downloaded on first use, as evident from the following firebase profiler data

[image: Android Profiler data]

As a result, the initial page load, (right on first time use) takes more than a minute, on a bad network, and 10 secs on best n/w which is a pretty bad user experience.

Another peculiar thing we observed is that, on keepSynced(false), profiler complains about non indexed queries; but this disappears for keepSynced(true). But for both these cases, the full data is downloaded
See the below screen grabs

No Unindexed queries,with keepSynced=true at path feed/feedID/tiles
[image: No UnIndexed queries]

Unindexed queries,with keepSynced=false at path feed/feedID/tiles
[image: UnIndexed queries]

Once the entire data is downloaded, the same is not downloaded again for subsequent calls. However, the page load time is still about 3-5 secs even when the data is loaded completely from persistence (verified by turning off the network and inspecting the firebase local logs)

May be the culprit is the index (or the lack thereof), but i got conflicting report from the profiler as i have shown above. Any help to reduce the data download size and page load time in this scenario would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Sreejith

Comment: did you get the solution I am also facing same problem even after pagination.